# PowerShell DSC secedit.exe SecEdit.exe Case Sensitive?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am a complete newbie to PowerShell and trying to write a first DSC script.

Install-Module -Name SecurityPolicyDsc

However when I run the configuration I get...

```
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies]
The term 'secedit.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (secedit.exe:) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

It seems that secedit.exe is actually called C:\WINDOWS\system32\SecEdit.exe on my Windows 10 system.  C:\ is NTFS.

Any idea how to make Powershell case insensitive when invoking secedit.exe?

Comment: PowerShell is not case-sensitive when invoking executables. I would check that your Path environment variable is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that C:\Windows\System32 was not on PATH as Bill suggested. I used Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables to set PATH to include C:\Windows\System32. I then restarted the PC so that services also picked up the change and now it works. Many thanks.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Start-DscConfiguration -Path c:\dsc -Wait -Force -Verbose
VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, ''methodName' = SendConfigurationApply,'className' = MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager,'namespace
Name' = root/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration'.
VERBOSE: An LCM method call arrived from computer COMPUTER with user sid S-1-5-21-1762681051-3184050464-2174412407-1001.
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies]
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies]
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Testing AccountPolicy: Enforce_password_history
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Current policy: 15 Desired policy: 15
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Testing AccountPolicy: Maximum_Password_Age
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Current policy: 42 Desired policy: 42
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Testing AccountPolicy: Minimum_Password_Age
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Current policy: 1 COMPUTERpolicy: 1
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Testing AccountPolicy: Minimum_Password_Length
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Current policy: COMPUTERDesired policy: 12
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Testing AccountPolicy: Password_must_meet_complexity_requirements
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Current policy: Enabled Desired policy: Enabled
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Testing AccountPolicy: Store_passwords_using_reversible_encryption
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]:                            [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies] Current policy: Disabled Desired policy: Disabled
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies]  in 0.4340 seconds.
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]: LCM:  [ Skip   Set      ]  [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies]
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[AccountPolicy]AccountPolicies]
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]
VERBOSE: [COMPUTER]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]    in  2.5460 seconds.
VERBOSE: Operation 'Invoke CimMethod' complete.
VERBOSE: Time taken for configuration job to complete is 2.791 seconds
```